# simple Java 2D Array with input

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java and got some work at school.
Now I don't know how to continue and I hope you can help me.

That's my code till now

```
    package bp;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BenzinP {

    private int row = 4;
    private int col = 4;
    private int[][] matrix;

    public BenzinP(int trow, int tcol) {

        this.row = trow;
        this.col = tcol;
    }

    public BenzinP(int trow, int tcol, int[][] m) {

        this.row = trow;
        this.col = tcol;
        this.matrix = m;
    }
    public int[][] fill(){ 
        int[][] data = new int[row][col]; 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int row = 0; row< matrix.length; row++){ 
              for(int col = 0 ;col< matrix.length; col++){ 
                  System.out.println("Date"); 
                  data[row][0] = in.nextInt(); 
                  System.out.println("Price"); 
                  data[row][1] = in.nextInt(); 
               }
              System.out.println(); 
          } 

           for(int row = 0; row< matrix.length; row++){
       for(int col = 0 ;col< matrix[row].length; col++){ 
             System.out.print(data[row][col]);
       } 
      System.out.println(); 
   }
         return data; 
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] ma = new int[3][2];
        BenzinP q2 = new BenzinP(3, 2,ma);
        q2.fill();
    }
}
```

The task is:
Create a Java program which can save the prices for gas for different days and can be outputted in different formats (sort for highes price or date).
You should use a 2D Array which can safe data for at least 30 days.
Also it should show the average, min. and max price.
Also the program should be outsourced in methodes etc.

I hope you can help and keep it simple.

Comment: So what do you want to ask?

Comment: Please look over your code and figure out a more specific question to ask. See also [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm not so in programming (have to do it for school). I want to ask, why my programm doesn't run correctly and what I have to do to do it right. I know that it might be annoying to someone who know how to program, but I try to understand and learn something and the teacher isn't realy a help. Because of that I have only really basic knowlegde.

Answer (score 0):

I will make some assumptions in order to be able to answer this:

if `BenzinP` is a class, that should not contain the main method. Only the main class in your project should contain the main, since that is what the JVM expects to be the "point of entry" in your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Since this is an exercise, dont worry so far about this.

Then, the `BenzinP` class has 2 constructors that are not really needed.

I suggest the following:

```
BenzinP(){
   this.matrix=new int[this.row][this.col];
}
```

Create the rest of the methods you want, such as query the highest value, lowest, etc.. and start your main

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    BenzinP q2 = new BenzinP();
    q2.fill();
    q2.getHighest();
    // q2.getLowest();
    // q2.getEtc();
}
```

As a suggestion, in order to search the highest and lowest value, iterate your array and compare that value with an initialized one, if its bigger/smaller, update the value, at the end of the array, return the initialized value:

```
public int getHighest(){
   int max = -2147483648; // the lowest possible integer.
   for(int i=0 i<this.row;i++){
      if(matrix[i][1]>max){
         max = matrix[i][1];
      }
   }
   return max;
}
```

Comment: I've tried as you say but the output isn't correct. If I enter the numbers they get calculated and not shown in a 30x2 grid

Comment: please, change `row` and `col` to the actual values, if the array is 30x2, then `row =30;` and `col=2`. Also note that you are putting 2 different informations on the same array... the "date" row (`matrix[0][whatever]` must not be calculated. I will edit the getHighest function to remove searching that line.... then again, it is your task to understand the code, not just copy/paste it.

Comment: As I said above, I'm new to Java. Till now I understand everything, but I don't get how I can use arrays.

Comment: Exactly, that is where I am trying to direct you.. an can be simplified as a repetition of several of the same data type... so creating `int example = new int[10]`would be closely coded to `int example0=0; int example1=0;.....int example9=0;`... when running the editted answer, does the output yeld what you want? If not, please, writte the input you have, and the expected output (such as input: `[0,3,76,7,128]`, expected output `q2.getHighest()` returns = `128`